# Electric Potential Due to Point Charge in a Plane

Tags: electromagnetism, differential-equations

In general physics courses, we are told that the electric potential a distance $r$ away from a point charge of magnitude $Q$ is given by $$ V = \frac{Q}{4\pi \epsilon r} \tag{1}. $$
Using this definition, it seems that, regardless of the geometrical dimension of our domain (i.e. whether we are looking at some subset of $\mathbb{R}$, $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$), we will still have that $V \propto \frac{1}{r}$.

However, upon studying partial differential equations, one finds out that (1) comes from the fundamental solution of Laplace's equation in 3D. Moreover, the fundamental solution to Laplace's equation in 2D (which is the same as the solution of $\nabla^2 V = \frac{Q}{\epsilon}\delta$), is given by

$$ V = -\frac{Q}{2\pi\epsilon} \ln(r). \tag{2} $$

Now, you will notice that in the above, $V < 0$ for $r > 1$, even if $Q$ is positive - which is non-physical. So, if we want to know the electric potential a distance $r$ away from a point charge in a planar region, what should we do?

Answer (score 3):

There is a real difference between doing physics in 2-dimension as opposed to working in a two dimensional subspace of ordinary space. For example we can talk about the potential of a point charge in a plane by simply ignoring the other coordinates, i.e.:
$$V=k{Q\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.$$
We are essentially asking about the value of the potential $V(x,y,z)$ for $z=0$, which is perfectly acceptable from a physical perspective. This kind of discussion, a two-dimensional problem embedded in a larger three-dimensional space, is different from asking what the electrostatic potential looks like if space itself is limited to only two dimensions. For the most part such truly two-dimensional solutions are purely hypothetical and would, I think, be of limited utility given that the universe is certainly not two-dimensional. Such models are of academic interest only.

Answer (score 2):

Your first equation is only true in 3-dimensional space. Even when you use it to solve problems that seem to be 2-dimensional, such as finding the potential due to a point charge in the $xy$-plane or finding the potential of a charged plate, you are assuming them to lie in 3-dimensional space.

In a truly 2-dimensional space (a universe with 2 spatial dimensions), the potential will indeed be described by your second equation.

> So, if we want to know the electric potential a distance r away from a point charge in a planar region, what should we do?

It depends on the context but it will most likely still be the first case. The other dimensions are unrealistic and seldom encountered in electrodynamics.

Comment: ```In a truly 2-dimensional space ... the potential will indeed be described by your second equation. ``` So, is it a mistake to regard the purely 2D case as having any physical significance? If we do regard it as having physical significance, we somehow need to rationalize the fact that $V \to -\infty$ as $r \to \infty$.

Comment: @ZacharyCandelaria Yes, it's theoretical. Physically, it is the consensus that our universe has 3 spatial dimensions and not 2. The fact that $V \to \infty$ as $r \to \infty$ is nothing surprising. You get that with infinite planes and line charges in 3D space too. That simply means that you cannot choose the reference to be at infinity. The potential *difference* between any two points, which is what physically matters, is still finite and well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Since we live in 3d the plane you are looking at is also in 3d so solution is the one in 3d. Only if you lived in flatland, situations would possibly be different.